# i need a way to input text into an already running program in terminal (linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, automation

(arch Linux)
basically i have a program running in terminal, i want a script to input some commands into it after a few hours.

I've tried:

- `./program < inputfile` ... the problem with this is that it instantly passes the commands, i need a wait or sleep function.
- `./bashscript | ./program` ... this does more of what i want just that at that point im unable to input any commands myself into the program. so that's also a no go.

update: more info.. the program is a minecraft bedrock server, the command i want to pass into is "stop", which will stop the program.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By modifying program, you can use `read`, a few options.

1) Halting the program(*) execution:

```
while read line; do $line; done < inputfile
```

2) Reading from the inputfile at specific times, explained more in [this example](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Reads_from_the_file_descriptor_(fd))

```
exec 3< /etc/path/to/inputfile #define this in the beginning of program

... program doing things

read 3 -u a b
```

(*) in both cases it would be important to understand more about the "program".

With this you are essentially halting it's [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) so will need to think whether it can gracefully stop executing everything it does(run read periodically? Halt it's state once it's finished?), and start accepting other command inputs?

Comment: its a minecraft bedrock server, so halting doesn't really sound like a great idea.